# Hover reacts only on left side of div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm having strange issue with hover. It looks like hover is being detected only on left side of the images, the right is inactive - this occurs on chrome. However on FF works fine. 
Here's [website](http://preview.greenlevel.pl)

I just have no more ideas about that... Has anyone met something like that, and knows how to change that?

There was something else, today it worked for me when I tunrd on this website, however after refresh, it stopped. Tried to clear cookies etc, but seems it's not that...

Upadate : Ok, nevermind i did manage to make it works. Added another div with

```
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
```

Thanks everyone for your time with this ;)

Comment: try putting `tabindex="1"` in your `div` tag....
however its working fine in my chrome

Comment: hm, thats even more strange than ;) this tabindex doesnt work as well

Comment: It's happening with my chrome, seems a strange one indeed..

Comment: I am not encountering any problem with it. As well left and right, up and down on the image the twist and turn. Sorry, cant seem to find the problem

Comment: Yea, thats why I said thats a really strange ;) however it's done now

Comment: I encountered this problem, and also answered here a question about exactly the same problem. It is related to the rotation of the element, not calculating exactly in Chrome, and half the element being under the body plane. I will try to find my old answer later ...

Comment: Okey, I will wait for your answer(maybe better solution), however I did manage to do this ;) at least it works for me now ;)